# MySqlDataAdapter doesn't fill DataTable

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, datatable

I would like to fill a DataTable object from MySql query, and display with DataGrid. The display part of my code works well (It shows a custom DataTable). Somehow the DataTable fill method won't work for me (i copied it from stackoverflow).

If i fill up DataTable from List with this function is works well

### DataTable t = ConvertToDataTable(userlist);

```
public DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;

    }
```

And below the other people's solution what won't work for me. i think table is null.

```
            string searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM USERS";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(searchQuery, connection);
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            GridView1.DataSource = table;
            this.GridView1.DataBind();
```

I also attached my MySQL database sample values.
It doesn't fill the DataGrid show no values. Any tips?

[image: MySQL DataBase sample values]

Comment: Use the debugger and check the content of the variable _table_ after the call to Fill. This code is correct and you should have all the record from the table Users in your DataTable variable.

Comment: It has no values;

Comment: It throws before Fill method because i called MySqlDataReader in the same connection...

Comment: In your code there is no DataReader. However that explains something. A connection cannot be used to execute other commands when it is busy serving a datareader